# Running large queries in the background MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am using MS SQL Server 2008
i have a table which is constantly in use (data is always changing and inserted to it)
it contains now ~70 Mill rows,
I am trying to run a simple query over the table with a stored procedure that should properly take a few days,

I need the table to keep being usable, now I executed the stored procedure and after a while every simple select by identity query that I try to execute on the table is not responding/running too much time that I break it

what should I do?
here is how my stored procedure looks like:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
update SOMETABLE
set
[some_col] = dbo.ufn_SomeFunction(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), another_column))
WHERE 
[some_col] = 243
```

even if i try it with this on the where clause (with an 'and' logic..) :

```
ID_COL > 57000000 and ID_COL < 60000000 and
```

it still doesn't work

BTW- SomeFunction does some simple mathematics actions and looks up rows in another table that contains about 300k items, but is never changed

Comment: What transaction level are you using? Is there an index on some_col? What kind of index is on the ID_COL?

Comment: the id_col is a primary identity (growing integer)... there are no indexes. readcommit transaction level...

Comment: I think the real problem mght be that your stored procedure is expected to take a few **days** to execute.  Are you sure that it couldn't be optimized?

Comment: If you do a "select some_col with (nolock) where id_col between 57000000 and 57000100", how long does that take? If it's taking more than a few minutes, abort the query and say "more than a few minutes" :-)

Comment: that select query took 0 seconds...

Comment: BTW .. running the query between 57000000 and 57001000 (1000 rows..) succeeded and took 21 seconds...

Comment: Hm. 21 seconds for 1000 records seems awfully slow. Do you think it's because the large column values are slow to transfer over the network (depending on where you execute the query) or because your server is in a general state of overload?

Comment: Michael Fredrickson - i am positive it cannot be optimized. and i cannot see why a business cant run somethings in the background that are excepted to take a while and keep the current flow working..

Comment: the query is executed on the server itself which is an ec2 instance that is running ms sql server 2008

Comment: the server cpu and storage is good buts is memory(ram 15gb) is always loaded

Comment: OK, not enough chars here, I will post an answer

Comment: One more question: What datatype is some_col?

Comment: some_col is an integer

Comment: Don't be so sure it cant be optimized, if you post `ufn_SomeFunction` we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective your server has a serious performance problem. Even if we assume that none of the records in the query

```
select some_col with (nolock) where id_col between 57000000 and 57001000
```

was in memory, it shouldn't take 21 seconds to read the few pages sequentially from disk (your clustered index on the id_col should not be fragmented if it's an auto-identity and you didn't do something stupid like adding a "desc" to the index definition).

But if you can't/won't fix that, my advice would be to make the update in small packages like 100-1000 records at a time (depending on how much time the lookup function consumes). One update/transaction should take no more than 30 seconds.

You see each update keeps an exclusive lock on all the records it modified until the transaction is complete. If you don't use an explicit transaction, each statement is executed in a single, automatic transaction context, so the locks get released when the update statement is done.

But you can still run into deadlocks that way, depending on what the other processes do. If they modify more than one record at a time, too, or even if they gather and hold read locks on several rows, you can get deadlocks.

To avoid the deadlocks, your update statement needs to take a lock on all the records it will modify at once. The way to do this is to place the single update statement (with only the few rows limited by the id_col) in a serializable transaction like

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  -- Error: You are in a transaction context already

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

-- Insert Loop here to work "x" through the id range
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE SOMETABLE
      SET [some_col] = dbo.ufn_SomeFunction(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), another_column))
      WHERE [some_col] = 243 AND id_col BETWEEN x AND x+500 -- or whatever keeps the update in the small timerange
  COMMIT
-- Next loop

-- Get all new records while you where running the loop. If these are too many you may have to paginate this also:
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  UPDATE SOMETABLE
    SET [some_col] = dbo.ufn_SomeFunction(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), another_column))
    WHERE [some_col] = 243 AND id_col >= x
COMMIT
```

For each update this will take an update/exclusive key-range lock on the given records (but only them, because you limit the update through the clustered index key). It will wait for any other updates on the same records to finish, then get it's lock (causing blocking for all other transactions, but still only for the given records), then update the records and release the lock.

The last extra statement is important, because it will take a key range lock up to "infinity" and thus prevent even inserts on the end of the range while the update statement runs.

Comment: i am sorry there might have been a misunderstanding - running the stored procedure between 57000000 and 57001000 took 21 seconds.. as you can see the select of 100 items took 0 sec... anyway your answer seems reasonable and i will give it a try and post back. thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's why I referenced the 1000-item query in the answer :-). I think that 21 seconds to select 1000 integers through a primary key with a clustered index and (nolock) is way too much. Because of the (nolock) the 21 seconds could not come from another blocking lock, and if you let it run directly on the server it can't be a network issue either. It's just raw performance of moving to the first index entry and taking 1000 ints from the following records. On what I would consider a normal server that should be well under one second, even with a pretty long disk queue.

Comment: Anyway, just experiment with the window size to get reasonable times for each update.

Comment: well the query is running for about 14 hours and its seems like its working fine so, thank you very much