# Efficient SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 and running the following stored procedure that needs to "clean" a 70 mill table from about 50 mill rows to another table, the `id_col` is `integer` (primary identity key)

According to the last running I made it is working good but it is expected to last for about 200 days:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- define the last ID handled
    DECLARE @LastID integer
    SET @LastID = 0
    declare @tempDate datetime
    set @tempDate = dateadd(dd,-20,getdate())
    -- define the ID to be handled now
    DECLARE @IDToHandle integer
    DECLARE @iCounter integer
    DECLARE @watch1 nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @watch2 nvarchar(50)
    set @iCounter = 0
    -- select the next  to handle    
    SELECT TOP 1 @IDToHandle = id_col
    FROM MAIN_TABLE
    WHERE id_col> @LastID and DATEDIFF(DD,someDateCol,otherDateCol) < 1
        and datediff(dd,someDateCol,@tempDate) > 0 and (some_other_int_col = 1745 or some_other_int_col = 1548 or some_other_int_col = 4785)
    ORDER BY id_col

    -- as long as we have s......    
    WHILE @IDToHandle IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF ((select count(1) from SOME_OTHER_TABLE_THAT_CONTAINS_20k_ROWS where some_int_col = @IDToHandle) = 0 and (select count(1) from A_70k_rows_table where some_int_col =@IDToHandle )=0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SECONDERY_TABLE
            SELECT col1,col2,col3.....
            FROM MAIN_TABLE WHERE id_col = @IDToHandle

            EXEC    [dbo].[DeleteByID] @ID = @IDToHandle --deletes the row from 2 other tables that is related to the MAIN_TABLE and than from the MAIN_TABLE
            set @iCounter = @iCounter +1
        END
        IF (@iCounter % 1000 = 0)
        begin
            set @watch1 = 'iCounter - ' + CAST(@iCounter AS VARCHAR)
            set @watch2 = 'IDToHandle - '+ CAST(@IDToHandle AS VARCHAR)
            raiserror ( @watch1, 10,1) with nowait
            raiserror (@watch2, 10,1) with nowait
        end
        -- set the last  handled to the one we just handled
        SET @LastID = @IDToHandle
        SET @IDToHandle = NULL

        -- select the next  to handle    
        SELECT TOP 1 @IDToHandle = id_col
        FROM MAIN_TABLE
        WHERE id_col> @LastID and DATEDIFF(DD,someDateCol,otherDateCol) < 1
            and datediff(dd,someDateCol,@tempDate) > 0 and (some_other_int_col = 1745 or some_other_int_col = 1548 or some_other_int_col = 4785)
        ORDER BY id_col
    END
```

Any ideas or directions to improve this procedure run-time will be welcomed

Comment: Hmmm... this seems like a very procedural approach to what should be a set-based problem.  You need to stop thinking in terms of row-by-row, and instead make use of Sql's ability to work very efficiently against sets of data.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the tables involved?  If you do, these triggers could be making everything take much longer.

Comment: It looks like the only thing that is forcing you to do this [row-by-agonizing-row](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) is the `DeleteByID` stored procedure... could you include this stored procedure's definition, so it could then be incorporated into a set-based solution?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try this:

```
Declare @Ids Table (id int Primary Key not Null)
Insert @Ids(id)
Select id_col
From MAIN_TABLE m
Where someDateCol >= otherDateCol
    And someDateCol < @tempDate -- If there are times in these datetime fields, 
                                -- then you may need to modify this condition.
    And some_other_int_col In (1745, 1548, 4785)
    And Not exists (Select * from SOME_OTHER_TABLE_THAT_CONTAINS_20k_ROWS
                    Where some_int_col = m.id_col)
    And Not Exists (Select * From A_70k_rows_table
                    Where some_int_col = m.id_col)
Select id from @Ids  -- this to confirm above code generates the correct list of Ids
return -- this line to stop (Not do insert/deletes) until you have verified @Ids is correct
-- Once you have verified that above @Ids is correctly populated, 
-- then delete or comment out the select and return lines above so insert runs.

      Begin Transaction
      Delete OT     -- eliminate row-by-row call to second stored proc
      From OtherTable ot
         Join MAIN_TABLE m On m.id_col = ot.FKCol
         Join @Ids i On i.Id = m.id_col 

      Insert SECONDERY_TABLE(col1, col2, etc.)
      Select col1,col2,col3.....
      FROM MAIN_TABLE m Join @Ids i On i.Id = m.id_col 

      Delete m   -- eliminate row-by-row call to second stored proc
      FROM MAIN_TABLE m 
      Join @Ids i On i.Id = m.id_col 

      Commit Transaction
```

Explaanation.

1. You had numerous filtering conditions that were not SARGable, i.e., they would force a complete table scan for every iteration of your loop, instead of being able to use any existing index.  Always try to avoid filter conditions that apply processing logic to a table column value before comparing it to some other value. This eliminates the opportunity for the query optimizer to use an index.
2. You were executing the inserts one at a time... Way better to generate a list of PK Ids that need to be processed (all at once) and then do all the inserts at once, in one statement.

Comment: well it seems good, i am running checks and post back if it all works fine, any way thanks a lot

Comment: well i tried to run this for small amount of information first (inside a loop where i went over the process for each 100000 rows but it made my db unavailable and after than i tried for each 1000 rows and still it made it in a few seconds unavailable to access SECONDERY_TABLE until and other related tables. only restarting the service cleared it out...

Comment: may i need to implement something from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480699/running-large-queries-in-the-backgroud-ms-sql

Comment: martin,  If the procedure fails after the Begin Transaction, it will leave locks on the table that will prevent access, explaining your symptoms. Until you figure out why the code is failing, either comment out the `Begin Transaction`, or, if it happens again,  type `RollBack Transaction` in the query window to regain access to the locked table.

Comment: If you write the code in blocks of 1000 records, (or whatever size) make sure that each iteration includes a `Begin Transaction` at the beginning of he iteration block, and a `commit transaction` at the end, or a `Rollback Transaction` if the iteration fails.

Comment: well it seems that this part is doing the problem :Delete m   -- eliminate row-by-row call to second stored proc
      FROM MAIN_TABLE m 
      Join @Ids i On i.Id = m.id_col

Comment: MAIN_TABLE is constantly changing (updating and writing), but the lines that are deleted are most likely (99.9%) not touched at all by any other query...